# While restarting apache getting erroe

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Hello team while starting my apache getting error mentioning my htttpd.conf file and error snipet
This is my httpd.conf file:-

```
# ServerRoot "/ebiz/apache/httpd"
ServerRoot "/ebiz/apache"

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
PidFile /ebiz/apache/run/httpd.pid

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
##

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen wevrd64620.uhc.com:8080
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module /ebiz/apache/httpd/modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User aemadmin
Group dce

#
# ExtendedStatus controls whether Apache will generate "full" status
# information (ExtendedStatus On) or just basic information (ExtendedStatus
# Off) when the "server-status" handler is called. The default is Off.
#
#ExtendedStatus On

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#

#User apache
#Group apache

### Section 2: 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin <AEM_Automation_OGS_DL@ds.uhc.com>

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If this is not set to valid DNS name for your host, server-generated
# redirections will not work.  See also the UseCanonicalName directive.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
# You will have to access it by its address anyway, and this will make
# redirections work in a sensible way.
#
#ServerName @@FQDN@@:@@PORT@@
ServerName wevrd64620.uhc.com:8080

#
# UseCanonicalName: Determines how Apache constructs self-referencing
# URLs and the SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT variables.
# When set "Off", Apache will use the Hostname and Port supplied
# by the client.  When set "On", Apache will use the value of the
# ServerName directive.
#
UseCanonicalName Off

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
#DocumentRoot "/ebiz/apache/httpd/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/html"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
#<Directory "/ebiz/apache/httpd/www/html">
<Directory "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Require all granted

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
# The index.html.var file (a type-map) is used to deliver content-
# negotiated documents.  The MultiViews Option can be used for the
# same purpose, but it is much slower.
#
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# TypesConfig describes where the mime.types file (or equivalent) is
# to be found.
#
TypesConfig "/etc/mime.types"

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

#
# Set a timeout for how long the client may take to send the request header
# and body.
# The default for the headers is header=20-40,MinRate=500, which means wait
# for the first byte of headers for 20 seconds. If some data arrives,
# increase the timeout corresponding to a data rate of 500 bytes/s, but not
# above 40 seconds.
# The default for the request body is body=20,MinRate=500, which is the same
# but has no upper limit for the timeout.
# To disable, set to header=0 body=0
#
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>

#
# EnableMMAP: Control whether memory-mapping is used to deliver
# files (assuming that the underlying OS supports it).
# The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted
# filesystems.  On some systems, turning it off (regardless of
# filesystem) can improve performance; for details, please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablemmap
#
#EnableMMAP off

#
# EnableSendfile: Control whether the sendfile kernel support is
# used to deliver files (assuming that the OS supports it).
# The default is on; turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted
# filesystems.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablesendfile
#
#EnableSendfile off

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
#ErrorLog /ebiz/app_logs/apache/httpd/logs/error_log
ErrorLog /ebiz/apache-logs/error_log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel info rewrite:debug

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D"  combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# "combinedio" includes actual counts of actual bytes received (%I) and sent (%O); this
# requires the mod_logio module to be loaded.
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

#
# The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
# If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
# container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
# define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
# logged therein and *not* in this file.
#
#CustomLog logs/access_log common

#
# If you would like to have separate agent and referer logfiles, uncomment
# the following directives.
#
#CustomLog logs/referer_log referer
#CustomLog logs/agent_log agent

#
# For a single logfile with access, agent, and referer information
# (Combined Logfile Format), use the following directive:
#

#CustomLog /ebiz/app_logs/apache/httpd/logs/access_log combined
CustomLog /ebiz/apache-logs/access_log combined

#
# Optionally add a line containing the server version and virtual host
# name to server-generated pages (internal error documents, FTP directory
# listings, mod_status and mod_info output etc., but not CGI generated
# documents or custom error documents).
# Set to "EMail" to also include a mailto: link to the ServerAdmin.
# Set to one of:  On | Off | EMail
#
ServerSignature Off

#
# Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is
# Alias fakename realname
#
# Note that if you include a trailing / on fakename then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  So "/icons" isn't aliased in this
# example, only "/icons/".  If the fakename is slash-terminated, then the
# realname must also be slash terminated, and if the fakename omits the
# trailing slash, the realname must also omit it.
#
# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If you
# do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
#
Alias /icons/ "/ebiz/apache/www/icons/"

<Directory "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/icons">
    Options -Indexes +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# WebDAV module configuration section.
#
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

#
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the realname directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the client.
# The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias directives as to
# Alias.
#


#
# "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
#<Directory "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/cgi-bin">
#    AllowOverride None
#    Options None
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>

#
# Redirect allows you to tell clients about documents which used to exist in
# your server's namespace, but do not anymore. This allows you to tell the
# clients where to look for the relocated document.
# Example:
# Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

#
# Directives controlling the display of server-generated directory listings.
#

#
# IndexOptions: Controls the appearance of server-generated directory
# listings.
#
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable

#
# AddIcon* directives tell the server which icon to show for different
# files or filename extensions.  These are only displayed for
# FancyIndexed directories.
#
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

#
# DefaultIcon is which icon to show for files which do not have an icon
# explicitly set.
#
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif

#
# AddDescription allows you to place a short description after a file in
# server-generated indexes.  These are only displayed for FancyIndexed
# directories.
# Format: AddDescription "description" filename
#
#AddDescription "GZIP compressed document" .gz
#AddDescription "tar archive" .tar
#AddDescription "GZIP compressed tar archive" .tgz

#
# ReadmeName is the name of the README file the server will look for by
# default, and append to directory listings.
#
# HeaderName is the name of a file which should be prepended to
# directory indexes.
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

#
# IndexIgnore is a set of filenames which directory indexing should ignore
# and not include in the listing.  Shell-style wildcarding is permitted.
#
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

#
# DefaultLanguage and AddLanguage allows you to specify the language of
# a document. You can then use content negotiation to give a browser a
# file in a language the user can understand.
#
# Specify a default language. This means that all data
# going out without a specific language tag (see below) will
# be marked with this one. You probably do NOT want to set
# this unless you are sure it is correct for all cases.
#
# * It is generally better to not mark a page as
# * being a certain language than marking it with the wrong
# * language!
#
# DefaultLanguage nl
#
# Note 1: The suffix does not have to be the same as the language
# keyword --- those with documents in Polish (whose net-standard
# language code is pl) may wish to use "AddLanguage pl .po" to
# avoid the ambiguity with the common suffix for perl scripts.
#
# Note 2: The example entries below illustrate that in some cases
# the two character 'Language' abbreviation is not identical to
# the two character 'Country' code for its country,
# E.g. 'Danmark/dk' versus 'Danish/da'.
#
# Note 3: In the case of 'ltz' we violate the RFC by using a three char
# specifier. There is 'work in progress' to fix this and get
# the reference data for rfc1766 cleaned up.
#
# Catalan (ca) - Croatian (hr) - Czech (cs) - Danish (da) - Dutch (nl)
# English (en) - Esperanto (eo) - Estonian (et) - French (fr) - German (de)
# Greek-Modern (el) - Hebrew (he) - Italian (it) - Japanese (ja)
# Korean (ko) - Luxembourgeois* (ltz) - Norwegian Nynorsk (nn)
# Norwegian (no) - Polish (pl) - Portugese (pt)
# Brazilian Portuguese (pt-BR) - Russian (ru) - Swedish (sv)
# Simplified Chinese (zh-CN) - Spanish (es) - Traditional Chinese (zh-TW)
#
AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

#
# LanguagePriority allows you to give precedence to some languages
# in case of a tie during content negotiation.
#
# Just list the languages in decreasing order of preference. We have
# more or less alphabetized them here. You probably want to change this.
#
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW

#
# ForceLanguagePriority allows you to serve a result page rather than
# MULTIPLE CHOICES (Prefer) [in case of a tie] or NOT ACCEPTABLE (Fallback)
# [in case no accepted languages matched the available variants]
#
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#
# AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
# file mime.types for specific file types.
#
#AddType application/x-tar .tgz

#
# AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
# information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
# Despite the name similarity, the following Add* directives have nothing
# to do with the FancyIndexing customization directives above.
#
#AddEncoding x-compress .Z
#AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

#
# AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
# actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
# or added with the Action directive (see below)
#
# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

#
# For files that include their own HTTP headers:
#
#AddHandler send-as-is asis

#
# For type maps (negotiated resources):
# (This is enabled by default to allow the Apache "It Worked" page
#  to be distributed in multiple languages.)
#
AddHandler type-map var

#
# Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
#
# To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
# (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

#
# Action lets you define media types that will execute a script whenever
# a matching file is called. This eliminates the need for repeated URL
# pathnames for oft-used CGI file processors.
# Format: Action media/type /cgi-script/location
# Format: Action handler-name /cgi-script/location
#

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# Putting this all together, we can internationalize error responses.
#
# We use Alias to redirect any /error/HTTP_<error>.html.var response to
# our collection of by-error message multi-language collections.  We use
# includes to substitute the appropriate text.
#
# You can modify the messages' appearance without changing any of the
# default HTTP_<error>.html.var files by adding the line:
#
#   Alias /error/include/ "/your/include/path/"
#
# which allows you to create your own set of files by starting with the
# /ebiz/apache/www/error/include/ files and
# copying them to /your/include/path/, even on a per-VirtualHost basis.
#

Alias /error/ "/ebiz/apache_cq_docroot/www/html/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/ebiz/apache/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Require all granted
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

#    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# ===================================================
# Server LoadModules-IfModule Settings
# ===================================================
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # disable TRACE and TRACK in the main scope of httpd.conf
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACK
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
  ## TO DO find alternative to this directive
  ##RewriteLog /ebiz/app_logs/jws/httpd/logs/rewrite.log
  ##RewriteLogLevel 0
</IfModule>

#
# The following directives modify normal HTTP response behavior to
# handle known problems with browser implementations.
#
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE [2-5]\..*" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

#
# The following directive disables redirects on non-GET requests for
# a directory that does not include the trailing slash.  This fixes a
# problem with Microsoft WebFolders which does not appropriately handle
# redirects for folders with DAV methods.
# Same deal with Apple's DAV filesystem and Gnome VFS support for DAV.
#
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully

#
# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
# with the URL of http://servername/server-status
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
#<Location /server-status>
#    SetHandler server-status
#    Require host example.org
#</Location>
####################################################################
# /ews-status disabled for now,
# moving away from Unix LDAP authentication
# Replacing with AD authentication, however there is no acceptable
# userid/password to place into the AuthLDAPBindDN/AuthLDAPPassword
# directives yet
#
# If you enter a set of credentials here, make sure that the
# credentials only have access to AD searching. Any credentials
# entered here are stored in plaintext and could present a
# security risk.
# TODO, this should be doable with apache2.4, look to enable ews status
# and mod cluster manager
##US138320##########################################################
<IfModule mod_status.c>
 ExtendedStatus on
 <Location /ews-status>
   SetHandler server-status
#   Require all granted
#   Require ip 10
#   Require host .uhc.com
#   order deny,allow
#   allow from 10 .uhc.com
 #  AuthType  basic
#   AuthName "WAS_ADMIN_eBiz"
#   AuthName
#   AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
#   AuthBasicProvider ldap
#   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=eaptestrtid2,CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=uhc,DC=com"
#   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=,"
#   AuthLDAPBindPassword "exec:/ebiz/apache/httpd/bin/waspass {xor}Ay0KEWltMhs="
#   AuthLDAPBindPassword ""
#   AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ad-ldap-prod.uhc.com:389/CN=Users,dc=ms,dc=ds,dc=uhc,dc=com?cn"
#  AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://:/?cn"
#   <RequireAll>
#   require ldap-group CN=WAS_ADMIN_eBiz,CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=uhc,DC=com
#     Require ldap-group CN=,
#     Require ip 10
#   </RequireAll>
 </Location>
</IfModule>

#
# Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
#  http://servername/server-info (requires that mod_info.c be loaded).
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
#<Location /server-info>
#    SetHandler server-info
#    Require host example.org
#</Location>

#
# Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
# enable the proxy server:
#
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#ProxyRequests On
#
#<Proxy *>
#    Require host example.org
#</Proxy>

#
# Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
# ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
# Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
#
#ProxyVia On

#
# To enable a cache of proxied content, uncomment the following lines.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html for more details.
#
#<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
#   CacheEnable disk /
#   CacheRoot "var/cache/httpd"
#</IfModule>
#


# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#


ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico
#########################################
#
# mod cluster directives
#
#########################################

Maxhost 50
Maxnode 50
## Uncomment below to handle more than 100 contexts
## Maxcontext 100

#
# Load config files from the config directory "/etc/httpd/conf.d".
#
#IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/mod_cluster.conf
#Include conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf
Include conf/httpd.conf-dontlog
Include vhosts.d/*.conf
```

AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Wed May 27 08:43:21.868723 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24103] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed May 27 08:43:21.869570 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 24103] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed May 27 08:43:21.869592 2020] [:error] [pid 24103] Module mod_proxy_balancer is loaded it must be removed  in order for mod_proxy_cluster to function properly
AH00016: Configuration Failed

Comment: How many kilobytes of comments do you expect someone to go through, when you just barf your full default config file with all the irrelevant content into the question? Apart from this being purely configuration related (read what the [tag:apache] tag and [help/on-topic] have to say about configuration questions, rather than programming to an API), you should really rather create a [mcve] - but on a different site, where this question is on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using mod_proxy_balancer module.You can not use mod_proxy_cluster with mod_proxy_balancer. Disable mod_proxy_balancer module and test.